# Why is dependency in package.json prefixed with @polymer?

Tags: npm, polymer, npm-install, sinon

When looking at [this package.json](https://github.com/Polymer/web-component-tester/blob/v6.4.0/package.json) I see two versions for sinonjs:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@polymer/sinonjs": "^1.14.1",
    ...
    "sinon": "^2.3.5",
    ...
  },
```

What is the difference between `sinon` and `@polymer/sinonjs`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node packages that start with `@namespace` are [scoped packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope). Typically this means an organization that wants a standardized naming convention for all of their packages that might have common names already taken in the global namespace.

In your example the organization is [Polymer](https://www.npmjs.com/~polymer) who has their own published version of `sinon`. As to why Polymer has their own published package of Sinon you'd have to ask them. The description suggests it's a workaround to access the Bower version of Sinon. That workaround probably wont be needed once Polymer makes the [jump to NPM](https://www.polymer-project.org/blog/2017-08-22-npm-modules).

> SinonJS proxy repository for the BowerJS package manager